# How Do I Limit Bandwidth For Connections On My Ubuntu VPS?

Tags: ubuntu, vps, bandwidth

I have a VPS with Ubuntu 12.04 installed, with a 35Gb limit each month (any more than that used and I have to pay). I normally use it with Zpanel to host a Joomla website, and keep the mail ports closed. There is no FTP, and I have set up a special port for SSH and have port scanning blocked.

A day or so ago, I noticed that the bandwidth used shot up to around the 3Gb outbound mark in a very short amount of time, up and down from there for about 2-3 hours. I stopped the apache2 service to see if it would stop it from happening again. I looked at the bandwidth used today and saw that it had shot up to over 1Gb outbound for several minutes, with smaller bursts of high bandwidth usage for a couple hours surrounding it.

Okay, now (10/10/14) I'm noticing a lot of traffic from port 48334 hitting a bunch of seemingly random ports on another IP address in California really fast. This is costing me about 6.5GB out so far in a short amount of time, about an hour or so. This is happening with Apache2 turned back on.

My main question is, how do I limit the bandwidth used by each connection to prevent such huge spikes?

My second one is, what could be causing this even though I had apache2 stopped and no open mail ports or FTP? I've just now installed IPTraf and set it to monitor and log traffic.

Comment: Before you can throttle bandwidth, you need to find out where it's going. You can use something like iftop or netstat to try and see what ports are be used and where the data is going. Ultimately, you may want to block any outbound traffic that you don't explicitly define via iptables, but you can make that determination one you get some more details.

Comment: @Unix-Ninja I just now installed IPTraf and set it to monitor and log traffic. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: nethogs is also useful, to see which processes are using the most network traffic.

Comment: This sounds serious. This sounds a bit like a virus. Please post the output of `sudo netstat -pantu`.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/8B7vTCCE x.x.x.x is my server IP, and #### is my custom SSH port. Also, whatever was going on has died down for now too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a security exploit in ZPanel 10.1.0 causing the server to be able to be used as part of a DDOS botnet. This is why the server was showing such odd activity as shown in the question as well as other issues including ones with SQL not mentioned in the question. The best way to solve this because it was already compromised would be to completely start over and not install the insecure ZPanel version.

Sources:
https://chunkhost.com/blog/16%2Fhuge_security_hole_in_zpanel_10_1

http://blog.0xlabs.com/2014/zpanel-10-1-0-unauthenticated-remote-root/

Comment: Seeing as how my hosting had found this issue, it also explains why I hadn't been charged for the extra bandwidth that was used.